# Java: Modifying System Properties for a Java App

Tags: java, properties

I am using a Java JMS GUI utility (HermesJMS), and in its runtime, I need to invoke:

`System.setProperty("user.name", "s24park");`

Is there a properties file within JDK(1.6.0.18) that stores system properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use -D flag when launching your application.

```
java -Duser.name=s24park YourClass
```

See [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/178539/Associate-Certification-SCJA/certification/What-java-D-command-line) post for more information. There is no **file** for System properties.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting link I had come upon recently:

http://leepoint.net/notes-java/io/30properties_and_preferences/40sysprops/10sysprop.html

You can also use the [Properties](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Properties.html) class - but this has nothing to do with "system" properties.
Any properties can be saved and loaded via this class

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your JVM may have one or more configuration files in which it is possible to create permanent system properties. That said, you really should be using [java.util.prefs.Preferences](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html).